# How to send email confirmation using gem devise&mailgun

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, devise, mailgun

I am having troubles with sending email confirmation using devise and mailgun.
I have installed devise and changed setting to send email but whenever I signup as a newcomer there is no confirmation email sent. 
Can anyone specifically explain how to do it? Thanks.

[config/environments/developments.rb](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xr8yo.png)

Comment: You can refer this material :https://www.railstutorial.org/book/account_activation_password_reset

Answer (score 3):

Try this ...........

**In your Gemfile**

gem 'mailgun_rails'

**To configure your Mailgun credentials place the following code in the corresponding environment file (development.rb, production.rb...)**

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :mailgun
config.action_mailer.mailgun_settings = {
        api_key: '<mailgun api key>',
        domain: '<mailgun domain>'
}
```

Hope this will work for you.